# Getting mouse position in entire screen Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, mouse, nsevent

I'm writing a program that needs to get the mouse position in the screen, (not just my view). I need to continuously update variables `xPos` and `yPos`. I've heard about subclassing nsview and adding `mouseDidMove`, but it is never called. (Yes, I set my window view to my custom view.) How can I do this?

Comment: I would recommend you add your code to your question.

Comment: @l'L'l There isn't any really. I just put `-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent)theEvent{ NSLog(@"moved");}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the NSWindow which contains the view to `window.acceptMouseMovedEvents = yes`. Also if you're just looking for mouse position in the screen consider `NSEvent.mouseLocation`